# Extract the Windows 10 retail product key

Tags: windows, windows-10, license, product-key

I tried to find the retail product key of Windows 10 with software like Nirsoft's ProduKey and Belarc Advisor. But the code they show doesn't match the code written on the official paper.

How do I get the right product key out of Windows?

Comment: I have noticed that these "key extractors" have been noticed by  Microsoft and they've altered key storage so that at least Belarc Advisor no longer functions.  I have not tested the Nirsoft product, but I imagine that Microsoft has made the product activation codes storage different now in Windows 10. I am not aware of ANY way to recover keys.

Comment: Please provide more information.  What version of Windows 10?  This a retail license?  Once installed on a machine you never need to enter the license due to how Windows 10 activates

Comment: Why would you want to do like this in the first place? Starting from Windows 10, the license is coupled to your Microsoft account, so as long as you have that, why do you need a license key? Using this argument, I guess Microsoft is not making it easy for third party tools to correctly extract a valid license key.

Comment: I need it because i have a other  pc which i want to do a fresh reinstall so i need the product code

Comment: @Xenioz - You should update your question to include the information I requested, without said information, I can't answer your question.  "code written on the official paper." - tells me you have a retail copy of Windows 10, which means you don't have OEM hardware, which means this is a very question to answer but I am withholding that answer for now because I am a information horder.  So update your question.

Comment: @rRamhound yes it is retail

Comment: "the code they show doesn't match with the code written on the official paper...How do I get the right product key?"  Look at the "official paper" you have...?

Comment: Are you sure the code on your "official paper" is correct? It's quite possible they typed in another key while installing the OS or cloned a pre-made image or something.